# How do i fit the image inside its parent div, nothing seems to work

Tags: html, css

Nothing seems to make the image size stay inside the dimensions of the div.
Here is the html code and the css code that corresponds to it.
I have tried max width max height as well as object contain and width and height set to 100%

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="center">
        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="SignIn">
                <div class="logo-container">
                    <img src="~/Assets/SignUp.png" alt="logo image" />
                </div>
                <h4>Sign up to Snippet</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="email" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Company" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Title" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
}

.logo-container {
    width: 80%;
    max-height: 400px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a JFiddle to show us?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JamesS The OP should be making a [mcve] in their question, not on jsfiddle, especially since questions can contain runnable snippets, just like on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to make the display on the div inline-block and set it's dimensions.  Then the img will take % from its parent

```css
div{
height:100px;
width:100px;
display:inline-block;}

img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#a{
width:50%;
height:50%;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src = "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
</div>


<div id='a'>
<img src = "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird!

- Is your css file linked properly?
- are you sure there are no spelling mistakes on class names?

maybe try setting img as `img {display: inline-block;}`

Else, you can just add a overflow of hidden on the img's parent div `.logo-container {overflow: hidden}`

Also check if you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` inside your `<head></head>`. It's a very important tag/attribute that displays page based on users screen size (makes your site responsive).